# Node js and LESS installation on Centos 7 for Symfony 2 application

Tags: node.js, symfony, less

I deal with an error with the installation of nodejs and less on a Centos 7 server.

My aim is to install a Symfony2 application on a new server (Centos 7). My application use less files, including for Twitter Bootstrap.

For Symfony2, I declare the following :

```
    assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: "/usr/local/bin/node"
            node_paths: ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules"]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

I followed this tutorial for the installation of node/npm and after less : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server.

Everything seems to bve alright, the command node -v works like npm -v. I launch this command for less :

```
sudo npm install less -g
```

I test a simple compilation of a style.less file in command line like :

```
$ lessc style.less style.css
```

No problem.

BUT when I run the Symfony2 command :

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

I have the error bellow :

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
```

An error occurred while running:

```
'/usr/local/bin/node' '/tmp/assetic_lessKtMIZV'
  Error Output:
  module.js:338
      throw err;
        ^
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'less'
>         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>         at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>         at require (module.js:384:17)
>         at Object. (/tmp/assetic_lessKtMIZV:1:74)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)

Node is well in `/usr/local/bin/node`

Node modules are well in : `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: It can't find less module. So try to install it locally without the -g. "npm i less" inside your app folder

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. It was in my parameters.yml files.

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1514993/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony2/installation-nodejs-less-symfony2-sous-centos-7-a/